# Error message: sam2p.exe has stopped working

Tags: errors

The following exception is being thrown when I compile .tex files using PCTeX V6: "sam2p.exe has stopped working."  I read at github that sam2p is a C++ image compression executable.   While I don't suppose this exception is specific to PCTeX, is there a solution or workaround to correct this situation?  Maybe a package is out of date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using a ten years old software, which needs an even older sam2p.exe for creating bitmap pictures, see [here](https://pctex.com/PCTeXTDS.html) .

There is another programm using sam2p.exe: pdfsizeopt. The author cares about sam2p, see [here](https://github.com/pts/sam2p) Maybe you could get a newer version there.

However, why don't you install a recent texlive oder MiKTeX? I found in another of your questions you didn't like MiKTeX, but then try texlive. You won't get much help here with a commercial, old software package, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very helpful.  Will look at MiKTeX.

Comment: So I installed MikTeX, and opened a .tex file in TeXWorks, and the fancybox package cannot be found after installing it with MiKTeX's package manager.   Thus, \usepackage{fancybox} comes up as an error.  I also need to install the mtpro2 Times math package, and don't have the .dtx for it, but need to copy the folder somewhere where TeXWorks will see the mtpro2.sty file.   Right now, TeXWorks cannot see the mtpro2.sty file after copying the mtpro2 contrib folder to C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mtpro2    Any suggestions?

Comment: I found the original mtp2fonts.zip.tpm and lucimatx.zip.tpm, and TeXWorks crashed when I opened mtp2fonts.zip.tpm.   Any work around?

Comment: Why don‘t you use the package manager of MikTeX? Sorry, now offline!

Comment: Got the issues solved. Thx for the answer and comments.